# Android Studio Error in SQLiteDatabase - Drop if table exists

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

The following code

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

always gives an error `index table trigger or view got if`

Why is that? I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: This is the correct command: `drop table if exists tablename`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drop your Table by using following code

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + YOUR_TABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Syntax:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
```

Incorrect Syntax:

```
DROP IF TABLE EXISTS
```